# How to read HDF5 bytes array resulting of string dataset

Tags: vb.net, arrays, hdf5

I use the **HDF5DotNet** libraries with VB.net. I need to read a string dataset (3000 items, each item len = 16). 
I use a **byte array** to store all the values but it's not easy to parse : I need to get a string by line and not a part of string. **Do you know a better way to store and parse the result ?**

Here my code:

```
'Load the file
Dim HDF5TestFileID As HDF5DotNet.H5FileId
HDF5TestFileID = H5F.open("C:\test.hdf5", H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY)

'Get datset and group id
Dim GroupRootId As HDF5DotNet.H5GroupId = H5G.open(HDF5TestFileID, "/")
Dim dataSetRN As H5DataSetId = H5D.open(GroupRootId, "MyItemsNames")

'Build byte array from the dataset
Dim readDataBackRN(16 * 3000) As Byte
Dim h5DataBackRN As New H5Array(Of Byte)(readDataBackRN)
Dim typeIdRN As H5DataTypeId = H5D.GetType(dataSetRN)
H5D.read(dataSetRN, typeIdRN, h5DataBackRN)

'try to parse the result but not easy to use data
Dim content as string = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readDataBackRN).Replace(" ", "<br>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You normally read the buffer, check if the string is complete and if not continue reading and append the new contents to the previous fragment and keep doing that until you find the end of line.

Can you do this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the string is complete but it's possible that one day I reach the limit of size. I cannot modify the  H5D.read method. I wonder if an simple array of byte is the best way ?
The better way would be to store result in a an array of array of bytes (1 array of byte per line of string) and not store all items in a single array of bytes ?
But I don't knwon if it's possible.